# Sum multiple rows (including duplicates)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the total sum/volume of multiple products (where one product may be used more than once)

I am hoping to run this as a SQL query to then speed up other aspects of my PHP script

Here is query I am running:

```sql
Select sum(`vol`) from dev where `name` IN ("A2","A1","A3","A1")
```

At the moment I get the sum of A2,A1 and A3. I want it to add A1 again to those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table to define the values:

```
select sum(dev.vol)
from (select 'A2' as name union all
      select 'A1' as name union all
      select 'A3' as name union all
      select 'A1' as name
     ) n join
     dev
     using (name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be generating a syntax error (#1267 - Illegal mix of collations) so I'll have a play around with that to see how to get around it. Only issue is generating a query like this in PHP from an initial string such as "A2,A1,A3,A1" starts to get difficult....

Comment: @Codingmedic . . . You can use the `collate` keyword to match collations.  That seems to be an issue with how the table is set up.  Perhaps you understand why the collation would be different from the database default.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiple by two with a `case..when` syntax :

```
select sum( case when `name` = 'A1' then `vol` * 2 else `vol` end ) 
  from dev 
 where `name` in ('A1','A2','A3')
```